# Vaultier is unusable for docker/ubuntu/debian (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, docker, debian

I am looking for a good Password safe for my Company. I wanted to test Vaultier, but it newer works as expected. Neither with Docker or other Platforms. There is always and error, if its Docker i get that output.
I'm no python specialist, but making pip install --upgrade  made the installation just missing the whole app.

i followed these guides https://www.vaultier.org/install/

```
sudo docker run -t -i --name vaultier -p 80:8088 rclick/vaultier:latest -e "VAULTIER_DOMAIN=vaultier.bla.com"
Error: invalid value for -e 'VAULTIER_DOMAIN=vaultier.bla.com': bad logging level name 'VAULTIER_DOMAIN=vaultier.bla.com'
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Starting the Docker without this value, gives a (400 Bad Request)

Using Ubuntu:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/bin/vaultier", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2720, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 592, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.4.1 (/opt/vaultier/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.7'))
```

Using Debian:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 295, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 707, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /opt/vaultier/venv/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-08foqW/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-UUDq9M-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/vaultier/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-08foqW/psycopg2
```

Any ideas on how to avoid that fail, or fixing this?

**UPDATE**

after the "six" problem solution i received a new error while running vaultier setup

```
      File "/opt/vaultier/venv/bin/vaultier", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Vaultier==0.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'vaultier')()
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vaultier/vaultier/runner.py", line 231, in main
    settings_envvar='VAULTIER_CONF'
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logan/runner.py", line 169, in run_app
    management.execute_from_command_line([runner_name, command] + command_args)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vaultier/vaultier/management/commands/setup.py", line 22, in handle
    management.call_command('syncdb')
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 159, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 68, in handle_noargs
    migrations = migration.Migrations(app_label)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 64, in __call__
    self.instances[app_label] = super(MigrationsMetaclass, self).__call__(app_label_to_app_module(app_label), **kwds)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.set_application(application, force_creation, verbose_creation)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 154, in set_application
    module = importlib.import_module(self.migrations_module())
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/django/migrations/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(SOUTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
For South support, customize the SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES setting
to point to the correct migrations module:

    SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
        'kombu_transport_django': 'kombu.transport.django.south_migrations',
    }
```

**UPDATE2 -FIX**

I couldnt find any solution online, so i tried another version of south and see there ... it works. :)

```
    >>> DB is initialized, you can now try to run Vaultier using 'vaultier runserver'
(venv)root@Vaultier:/opt/vaultier# vaultier runserver
```

In the requirements.txt from vaultier, or setup.py ... doesnt matter which one you use. just set "South==1.0.2" 
Dont forget to set "Six==1.9"

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem as you, the steps I did in Ubuntu to fix were:

1. Download Vaultier last version: `wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/V/Vaultier/Vaultier-0.7.5.tar.gz`
2. Unpack & unzip it: `tar -xzvf Vaultier-0.7.5.tar.gz`
3. Edit `setup.py` file and find the line that contains `six==1.4`,
   change for this `six==1.9`,
4. Install it running: `python setup.py install`

Comment: hi, thank you very much and sorry for the late response. Didnt recognize that i received an answer.
I did what u said and received in after install an error: "mock requires setuptools>=17.1. Aborting installation
error: Setup script exited with 1
"

Comment: if anyone receives the above error, use this on ubuntu or similar systems: wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python

Comment: how did you finish the installation? after installing the dependencies i want to run  `vaultier init`, and receive that `  File "/usr/local/bin/vaultier", line 9, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2720, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2380, in load
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2386, in resolve
ImportError: No module named vaultier.runner
`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna use the Docker Image the current Vaultier documentation is kind of confusing.

Try this:

1. Pull the latest Image (do not run the image!)

   `sudo docker pull rclick/vaultier:latest`
2. Run the Image (replace EXAMPLE.COM with your desired Domain):

   `sudo docker run --name vaultier -p 80:80 -e "VAULTIER_DOMAIN=EXAMPLE.COM" rclick/vaultier:latest`

Comment: how to troubleshoot the "no email" problem with Vaultier? I have setup the Vaultier docker and all mail settings properly, but the "invite" is not sending any mails out - how to debug it? which logs / locations to check?

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue - no email coming out - it isn't even connecting to the mail server, per those logs

Comment: @crovers unfortunately, no - couldn't resolve the error and gave up.

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem As an FYI, I did "fix" this - I changed the source code to send synchronously rather than async (I changed a true to a false in one of the mail sending calls). Seems to work fine, just very hacky :(

Answer (score 1):

After struggling many days, i found out how to install it :

If you install it with "apt-get install vaultier", then you will have the South and Six version issue, so just run in parallel "while [ 1 ]; do sed -i 's/six==1.4.1/six==1.9/' /tmp/pip*/setup.py; sed -i 's/South==0.8.4/South==1.0.2/' /tmp/pip*/setup.py;done 2>/dev/null"

After the installation succeed, if you run "vaultier check" and you got "No module named vaultier.runner", set the PYTHON_PATH variable : "export PYTHONPATH="/opt/vaultier/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vaultier"", go to /opt/vaultier/venv/bin and try again.

I got issues with sending email (to invite and share with others). The environment variable FROM_EMAIL or VAULTIER_FROM_EMAIL wasn't effective, so Vaultier was using "noreply@vauliter.YOURDOMAIN.LOCAL" in the "from:" of the SMTP exchange.
I manually entered the desired email in  "/opt/vaultier/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vaultier/vaultier/business/mailer.py" line 33 : self.from_email = 'vaultier@YOURDOMAIN.COM'

If i got enough time, i'll make an OVA based on a CentOS 7 fully operationnal.

By the way, it's a good app, looks nice and do well it's job. By the way, it's the only free one that you can host. There was another one but ugly and not so easy to use.